# Send bytes to serial port

Tags: c++, windows, api

I'm trying to make a Windows program that sends data to a microcontroller, through serial port (USB emulating COM port).

Until now, I made it with ASCII strings, but I have to do a job with a classmate, that told me that I don't have to do that; That I have to send to the serial port the actual bytes that he needs to use (he is programming the microcontroller I am programming the Windows interface).

I always used `WriteFile()` with ASCII strings, in the form:

```
WriteFile(handlePort, bufferPort, strlen(buffer_puerto), &nBytes, NULL);
```

I have to send a byte chain, like `10000001 10010001 0000000 10100001 11101101`.

The problem is that when `WriteFile()` detects the third byte `00000000`, it is interpreted like a null character `'\0'` and does not send more bytes.

Please, can anyone help me? Is there any way to send all of the bytes (after the third `00000000`) without losing any information?

Is there another function apart from `WriteFile()` which can do that?  How should I do it?

Comment: The problem is that you call `strlen` which stops at the null byte

Answer (score 3):

It's not WriteFile, it's strlen that's stopping at 0. You want:

```
...
int len = 5;
char bytes[] = {0x81, 0x91, 0x0, 0xa1, 0xed};
WriteFile(handlePort,bytes,len,&nBytes,NULL);
if (len != nBytes) {
    error("Not all bytes written!");
}
...
```

Comment: Yes, you have to use `char[]` (or even `BYTE[]`).

Comment: Oops, well spotted

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using `strlen` which is designed to stop at a zero byte. `WriteFile` is fine; it just needs you to tell it the right number of bytes to write.